# delete or disable service endpoints programmatically?

Tags: 7, services

I am trying to programmatically disable a service endpoint, but I am not able to achieve it using the following code.

```
$endpoint = services_endpoint_load('my_service');
$endpoint->disabled = TRUE;
services_endpoint_save($endpoint);
```

Is there any other way to disable the service endpoint?
Is it possible to delete it?

Comment: Try this code. $endpoint = services_endpoint_load('my_service'); $endpoint->resources['resource_name']['actions']['action_name']['disabled'] = 0; services_endpoint_save($endpoint);

Comment: the code you have sent is to disable resources not the endpoints.